# SVN to GIT Migration lock issue

Tags: git

Whenever am doing fetching for a repo , I got this error

error: could not lock config file /SVN2GIT_NEW/svn2github_migration/cfe-sd-mfw/cfe-sd-mfw-HealthRepository/.git/svn/.metadata: File exists
config svn-remote.svn.branches-maxRev 100: command returned error: 255

I tried deleting .metadata file but not getting deleted. Please help me on this

Comment: What migration software are you using?

Comment: Please edit your question to include more details about which tools and versions you're using.